# How to add a background image while creating a text image using php?

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm currently using the following script--

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 115, 150, 195);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'My Name';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'AGENCYB.TTF';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

But I want to add a background image too. Please help, I'm new to this function especially.

Comment: Functions you will need: [`imagecreatefromjpeg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) or one of the other "from" functions, and [`imagecopy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) or [`imagecopyresampled()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like the following work for you? You want to open the image you want to use as the background, and then write your text over the top.

```
    <?php
    // Set the content-type
    header('Content-type: image/png');

    /* Attempt to open */
        $im = @imagecreatefrompng('backgroundimage.png');

        /* See if it failed */
        if(!$im)
        {
            // Create some colors
        $white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
        $black = imagecolorallocate($im, 115, 150, 195);
        imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

        // The text to draw
        $text = 'My Name';
        // Replace path by your own font path
        $font = 'AGENCYB.TTF';

        // Add some shadow to the text
        imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

        // Add the text
        imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

        // Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
        imagepng($im);
        imagedestroy($im);


        }else
    {
         //you want to do something here if your image didn't open like maybe fpassthru an alternative image
    }
?>
```

Comment: There must be `if($im)` instead of `if(!$im)`