# How to use background image instead of color in PHP imagecolorallocate()

Tags: php, html, css

I want to create a custom captcha. 
so i need to convert text and background image as single image;
 Now i can use only background color in **imagecolorallocate()**
here is my code

`<?php`
  `$text = rand (1000, 9999);`
  `$my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 );`
  `$background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img,255, 255, 255);`
  `$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 255 );`
  `$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 255, 255, 255 );`
  `imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, $text,  $text_colour );`
  `imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );`
  `imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );`
  `header( "Content-type: image/png" );`
  `imagepng( $my_img );`
  `imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );`
  `imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );`
  `imagecolordeallocate( $background );`
  `imagedestroy( $my_img );`
   `?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **imagecreatefromjpg** PHP function, or any of its associated functions based on the image type, like **imagecreatefrompng**.

This will create an image element in PHP from the selected file that you can use as a background file.

From the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php).

Your next option is to use **imagecopymerge()** that will use an existing image element and merge it with another image.  Info from the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I want something like this http://solvecaptchas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Captcha_Creator_PHP_Script-358301.gif     can i do this in imagecreatefromjpg()  ?

Comment: Yes, you can make the background images look like that link you sent.  However, you will need to do more formatting or use transparent images as the text.

Comment: No problem.  If this answers your question please mark it as the correct answer.  Thank you!

Comment: i used code from php manual -bt this statement is confusing me   /* Attempt to open */
    $im = @imagecreatefrompng($imgname);

    /* See if it failed */
    if(!$im)
new image display only if no image is loaded

Comment: Get rid of your $my_img = imagecreate( 200, 80 ); line and change it with $my_img = imagecreatefrompng("imagename");  Make sure to replace "imagename" with the path and filename of the image you want to use as the background

Answer (score 2):

```
 <?php
 function LoadJpeg($imgname)
 {
  if(!$im)
{
    /* Create a black image */
    $im  = imagecreatetruecolor(150, 30);
    $bgc = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $tc  = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

    imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 150, 30, $bgc);

    /* Output an error message */
    imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, 'Error loading ' . $imgname, $tc);
}

return $im;
}

 header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
 $img = LoadJpeg('bogus.image');
 imagejpeg($img);
 imagedestroy($img);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For adding a background to your new image you need to use [`imagecreatefrompng`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) instead of `imagecreate`.

You can go through another stack overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355622/how-to-add-a-background-image-while-creating-a-text-image-using-php)